io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidationException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: no JSON Text to read from input
I am trying to validate response body on matching the JSON schema using Rest Assured 5.4.0 and receiving:
io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidationException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: no JSON Text to read from input
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 1]

I have validated the schema using online JSON Schema validator and schema is valid.
Code:
        given().headers(
                        "Authorization", "Bearer " + token,
                        "Content-Type", ContentType.JSON,
                        "Accept", ContentType.JSON)
                .body(getRemnant())
                .when().log().all()
                .post(baseUrl + loadRemnantEndPoint)
                .then().log().all()
                .assertThat()
                .body(JsonSchemaValidator.matchesJsonSchemaInClasspath("assortment/schema/postResponseSchema.json"))

schema:
enter image description here
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "date": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "stocks": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "nnt": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "sku": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "qnt": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "supInn": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "supId": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "supDate": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "nds": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "gnvls": {
              "type": "boolean"
            },
            "dp": {
              "type": "boolean"
            },
            "man": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "exp": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "prcMan": {
              "type": "number"
            },
            "prcOpt": {
              "type": "number"
            },
            "prcOptNds": {
              "type": "number"
            },
            "prcRet": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "prcReestr": {
              "type": "number"
            },
            "prcGnvlsMax": {
              "type": "number"
            },
            "sumOpt": {
              "type": "number"
            },
            "sumOptNds": {
              "type": "number"
            },
            "mrGnvls": {
              "type": "number"
            },
            "tag": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "nomenclatureId": {
              "type": "integer"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "nnt",
            "sku",
            "qnt",
            "supInn",
            "supId",
            "supDate",
            "nds",
            "gnvls",
            "dp",
            "man",
            "exp",
            "prcMan",
            "prcOpt",
            "prcOptNds",
            "prcRet",
            "prcReestr",
            "prcGnvlsMax",
            "sumOpt",
            "sumOptNds",
            "mrGnvls",
            "tag",
            "nomenclatureId"
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "nnt": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "sku": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "qnt": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "supInn": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "supId": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "supDate": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "nds": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "gnvls": {
              "type": "boolean"
            },
            "dp": {
              "type": "boolean"
            },
            "man": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "exp": {
              "type": "string"
            },
            "prcMan": {
              "type": "number"
            },
            "prcOpt": {
              "type": "number"
            },
            "prcOptNds": {
              "type": "number"
            },
            "prcRet": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "prcReestr": {
              "type": "number"
            },
            "prcGnvlsMax": {
              "type": "number"
            },
            "sumOpt": {
              "type": "number"
            },
            "sumOptNds": {
              "type": "number"
            },
            "mrGnvls": {
              "type": "number"
            },
            "tag": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "nomenclatureId": {
              "type": "integer"
            }
          },
          "required": [
            "nnt",
            "sku",
            "qnt",
            "supInn",
            "supId",
            "supDate",
            "nds",
            "gnvls",
            "dp",
            "man",
            "exp",
            "prcMan",
            "prcOpt",
            "prcOptNds",
            "prcRet",
            "prcReestr",
            "prcGnvlsMax",
            "sumOpt",
            "sumOptNds",
            "mrGnvls",
            "tag",
            "nomenclatureId"
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "date",
    "stocks"
  ]
}

Error:
io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidationException: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: no JSON Text to read from input
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 1]

    at io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator.matchesSafely(JsonSchemaValidator.java:233)
    at io.restassured.module.jsv.JsonSchemaValidator.matchesSafely(JsonSchemaValidator.java:75)
    at org.hamcrest.TypeSafeMatcher.matches(TypeSafeMatcher.java:67)
    at io.restassured.internal.assertion.BodyMatcher.validate(BodyMatcher.java:82)
    at io.restassured.internal.assertion.BodyMatcherGroup.lambda$validate$0(BodyMatcherGroup.java:30)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1708)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:921)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:682)
    at io.restassured.internal.assertion.BodyMatcherGroup.validate(BodyMatcherGroup.java:30)
    at io.restassured.internal.assertion.BodyMatcherGroup$validate$3.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:157)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure.validate(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:499)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl$HamcrestAssertionClosure$validate$1.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:125)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:139)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.validateResponseIfRequired(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:696)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.this$2$validateResponseIfRequired(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.doInvoke(PlainObjectMetaMethodSite.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:198)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:62)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:171)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:185)
    at io.restassured.internal.ResponseSpecificationImpl.body(ResponseSpecificationImpl.groovy:107)
    at io.restassured.internal.ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.body(ValidatableResponseOptionsImpl.java:238)
    at AssortmentApiTest.loadRemnantTest(AssortmentApiTest.java:55)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:57)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:232)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:55)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: no JSON Text to read from input
 at [Source: (StringReader); line: 1, column: 1]



So what is returned by your endpoiint? Looks like it is not valid json.

Yes, that's the point(( Schema is ok, but response body is not valid json, thanks a lot!
